# Concatenate two vectors while preserving order in R

Tags: r, concatenation

This is hard to explain, so I'll try and then leave a simple example. When I concatenate the vectors, I would like the first element of each vector next to each other, then the second elements next to each other, etc. See example below.

```
x <- c("a","b","c")
y <- c(1,2,3)
c(x,y)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "1" "2" "3"
```

However, I would like the following:

```
[1] "a" "1" "b" "2" "c" "3"
```

I'm sure there is an answer on here already, but I'm having trouble putting in the right search. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I dupe tagged it, but i had to search for some time to get the dupe.  Also, the general answer is not in the dupe tag.  So, I am keeping it heere

Answer (score 3):

An option would be to `rbind` and then concatenate

```
c(rbind(x, y))
#[1] "a" "1" "b" "2" "c" "3"
```

---

and for general case when the vectors are not of same length, `order` on the sequence of elements concatentated

```
c(x, y)[order(c(seq_along(x), seq_along(y)))]
#[1] "a" "1" "b" "2" "c" "3"
```

Comment: Nice and elegant. Thanks! Is this answered elsewhere? If so, I'll remove the question.

Comment: @ACE Could be, but it is better to check google before posting the question.

Comment: @ACE If you want you can remove the question.  But, consider the facts 1) Avg life of a human being ~ 60-70 years, 2) Time flow is one-directional